# Check if a time is previous than other in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a time is earlier than another time using JavaScript or any JavaScript library.

For example I have `t1=12:45:30` and `t2=12:45:35` I want to check if t1 is earlier than t2. How can I easily do it using JavaScript?

I was trying the following code:

```
if(t1<t2)
```

But it is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: `t1=12:45:30` is not valid JavaScript. How are you *actually* creating your dates?

Comment: yes it's not a valid Js date,one approach would be to split the your date in an array and den compare..

Comment: If the t1 is string, first split it with arr = t1.split(":") and then multiply the values with parseInt( arr[0] )*60*60 +  parseInt( arr[1] )*60 + parseInt( arr[2] )

Comment: is there no built in function in d3.time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, "12:34:42" is not a valid javascript timestamp which precludes you from using the `Date` object, but you could easily convert the time string into seconds and compare those values:

```
var seconds = function(time) {
  return time.split(":").reverse().reduce(function(p,c,i) { 
    return p + (parseInt(c, 10) * (Math.pow(60, i)));
  }, 0);
}

if(seconds(t1) < seconds(t2)) {
  ... do stuff
}
```

Or if you have ES6 available:

```
const seconds = (time) => time.split(":").reverse().reduce((p,c,i) => {
    return p + (parseInt(c, 10) * (Math.pow(60, i)));
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 24 hour time you can remove the colons and subtract the digits 
to compare two times.

A negative return indicates the first argument is less than the second.

Positive means the first is greater, and zero means they are identical.

```
function compareHMS(hms1, hms2){
    return hms1.replace(/\D+/g,'')-hms2.replace(/\D+/g,''); 
}
```

**compareHMS('12:45:30', '12:45:35');**

// returned value: (Number) **-5**

Comment: This seems to be the less complex answer and the one that I use.